# Flexible log parser library in Java

Tags: java, parsing, logging

The library would receive log files (access log of tomcat and others) in different, sometimes proprietary formats unknown in advance and should parse them and extract certain fields - like timestamp, ip, etc...

Either open source or proprietary solutions are acceptable.

Answer (score 5):

http://jffp.sourceforge.net/

https://github.com/otros-systems/otroslogviewer

You can also try splunk, but it is costly